# Can I run spark 2.0.* artifact on a spark 2.2.* stand-alone cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I am aware of the fact that with the change of major version of spark (i.e. from 1.* to 2.*) there will be compile time failures due to changes in existing APIs.

As per my knowledge spark guarantees that with minor version update (i.e. 2.0.* to 2.2.*), changes will be backward compatible.

Although this will eliminate the possibility of compile-time failures with upgrade, would it be safe to assume that there won't be any run time failure too if submit a job on spark 2.2.* stand alone cluster using an artifact(jar) created using 2.0.* dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

> would it be safe to assume that there won't be any run time failure too if submit a job on 2.2.* cluster using an artifact(jar) created using 2.0.* dependencies?

Yes.

I'd even say that there's no concept of a Spark cluster unless we talk about the built-in Spark Standalone cluster.

In other words, you deploy a Spark application to a cluster, e.g. Hadoop YARN or Apache Mesos, as a application jar that may or may not contain Spark jars and so disregard what's already available in the environment.

---

If however you do think of Spark Standalone, things may have been broken between releases even between 2.0 and 2.2 as the jars in your Spark application have to be compatible with the ones on JVM of Spark workers (they are already pre-loaded).

I would **not** claim full compatibility between releases of Spark Standalone.

Comment: Actually, I was talking about spark stand-alone cluster. I'll update the question to avoid the confusion.

Comment: If it's about spark standalone, I'd not be 100% sure. Answer updated.