# pyspark 1.4 how to get list in aggregated function

Tags: python, list, pyspark, apache-spark-1.4

I want to get list of a column values in aggregated function, in pyspark 1.4. The `collect_list` is not available. Does anyone have suggestion how to do it?

Original columns:

```
ID, date, hour, cell
1, 1030, 01, cell1
1, 1030, 01, cell2
2, 1030, 01, cell3
2, 1030, 02, cell4
```

I want output like below, `groupby (ID, date, hour)`

```
ID, date, hour, cell_list
1, 1030, 01, cell1, cell2
2, 1030, 01, cell3
2, 1030, 02, cell4
```

But my pyspark is in 1.4.0, `collect_list` is not available. I can't do:
`df.groupBy("ID","date","hour").agg(collect_list("cell"))`.

Comment: /opt/spark1.4/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-client --num-executors 37 xxx.py

Answer (score 0):

*Spark 1.4 is old, not supported, slow, buggy and compatible with current versions. You should really consider upgrading Spark installation*

Enable Hive support, register `DataFrame` as a temporary table, and use

```
sqlContext  = HiveContext(sc)

df = ...  # create table using HiveContext
df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql(
  "SELECT id, date, hour, collect_list(cell) GROUP BY id, date, hour FROM df" 
)
```

Since [you use YARN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684855/pyspark-1-4-how-to-get-list-in-aggregated-function#comment82329830_47684855) you [should should be able to submit any version of Spark code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47670531/8371915), but it might require placing custom PySpark version on the `PYTHONPATH`.